# How can i fetch data from django models(database) using celery(asynchronously) from previously existing data

Tags: django, celery

tasks.py

```
    import string
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
    from celery import shared_task

    @shared_task
    def create_random_user_accounts(total):
        for i in range(total):
            username = 'user_{}'.format(get_random_string(10, string.ascii_letters))
            email = '{}@example.com'.format(username)
            password = get_random_string(50)
            User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
        return '{} random users created with success!'.format(total)
```

views.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from .tasks import create_random_user_accounts
    from django.http import JsonResponse

    def users(request):
        obj = list(User.objects.values())
        create_random_user_accounts.delay(20)
        return JsonResponse(obj,safe=False)
```

here i am inserting some random datas to User model using celery
And it is working while fetching same data.

But, i want to fetch 'existing data' from database 'without inseting' them on same request.
Please share me some idea how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method #1 do the insert off a `POST` and then retrieve via a `GET`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .tasks import create_random_user_accounts
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class UserView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = list(User.objects.values())        
        return JsonResponse(obj,safe=False)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        create_random_user_accounts.delay(20)    
        obj = list(User.objects.values())        
        return JsonResponse(obj,safe=False)
```

Method #2 is just to remove the call to create_random_user_accounts, since that is what is creating the accounts:

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from .tasks import create_random_user_accounts
    from django.http import JsonResponse

    def users(request):
        obj = list(User.objects.values())
        # create_random_user_accounts.delay(20)
        return JsonResponse(obj,safe=False)
```